# change name of appendices

Tags: appendices, naming

I am trying to change the name of the Appendices. This is what I've done:

```
\begin{appendices}
\input{muonSF}
\input{Wmass}
\input{BDTCrossCheck}
\end{appendices}
```

using the package appendices. My problem is that I need to change the name of appendix to Anexo (spanish for appendix), and also I need a page before all appendices with only the word Anexo.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `\appendixpage` to get a heading in the style of a `\part`; to change the name appearing in this heading you need to redefine `\appendixpagename`; to change the name used for the appendices, you need to redefine `\appendixname`. Here's a little example (I assumed that you are using `babel` with the `spanish` option):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

\addto\captionsspanish{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
}

\begin{document}

\appendixpage
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Anexo Uno}
\chapter{Anexo Dos}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make it more clear, the negative number of rows is necessary to tell LaTeX the color extends to the 2 previous rows, so it must be adapted to an arbitrary number or combined rows, while placing the multirow command in the last of the combined rows. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the **Babel** package by Johannes Braams. You just have to include it specifying the language your want to display in your document: *spanish*, *russian*, etc.

`\include[spanish]{babel}`

There's detailed information about it at [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) and some more practical examples at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Babel).

I thought it was a good idea to point this out since it's a more practical way than having to redefine names all the time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

If you work with the `appendix` package and simply want to change the name to something else than *Appendices*, the one-liner solution is:

```tex
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{YourAppendixName}
```